# How to add the OpenCV library to my Python library?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, numpy

Hey I'm new to python and I have to do a project that requires openCV and Numpy. I'm currently using both Pycharm and Spyder as my IDE's and Windows as an operating system. While found a executable for numpy. For the openCV I was given a folder with about 300mb worth of files from the official site.

I ran the command

"setx -m OPENCV_DIR //MY DIRECTORY"

Like the official website instructed and it was successfully but I still can use the openCV library. Can someone please tell me what to do with the folder, the main website is tricky to me. I am still in college undergrad and I humbly acknowledge my confusion. Even if the answer is simple, please scold me but let me know what to do.

Comment: find the `cv2.pyd` file in the opencv folder, and copy to python/lib/site-packages

Comment: in linux: sudo apt-get install python-opencv

Comment: A few more steps detailed following what berak mentioned above: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html

Comment: I ended up just installing it on Linux because of how simple it was, but what berak and optimist suggested works as well. At the end I just choose to go with the Linux route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Ubuntu, you can install OpenCV module by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

you can Import like this

```
import cv2
```

Comment: I'm using windows but I may consider installing a virtual machine if I can